# Change external SVG text with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm having an issue changing the text in an external SVG. I've found a number of solutions listed here but none of them have worked.

Adding a listener:

```
document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener('onload', func);
```

The function:

```
function func () {

    var ele = document.getElementById('id1'),
        svg = ele.contentDocument,
        p = svg.getElementById('id2');

    alert(p.textContent);
    p.textContent = 'test';

}
```

The first time I load it, p returns null. On the second load the alert returns the correct text within the SVG text element but the text is not updated by the next statement.

Why is it not working on the first load and why is the text not changing

Comment: What sort of element are "id1" and "id2"?  Can you create a working code snippet, or at least add the relevant HTML and SVG.

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg height="90" width="200">
  <text x="10" y="20" style="fill:red;">Several lines:
    <tspan x="10" y="45">First line.</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="70">Second line.</tspan>
  </text>
  <text x="40" y="60">more text</text>
  <text>will not display as x and y are missing</text>
</svg>
```

You need to set the x and y attribute for an element to be displayed. Also the alert should happen after you set the value of the text element:

```
p.textContent = 'test';
alert(p.textContent);
```

Comment: The text element is visible and has default text in it so I wouldn't think there would be an issue with the x or y values. I tried adding them and it doesn't seem to have any effect. I was expecting the alert to initially return the default text.

Comment: Try innerHTML instead. IE8 or earlier does not support textContent